# LaTeX citation with included chapters

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, include, mendeley

this is my first time asking a question at StackExchange and my first time using Latex to write something so pls excuse some form mistakes. I already invested a lot of time to find my mistake while quoting but it turns out my citation is correct, because at a Friends device it works properly. My easy example for the Problem is:

```
\begin {document}

\include{cittest2}
\cite{Hecht2002}

\bibliography{test1}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

%this is the main document and this the included cittest2:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}

test \cite{Hecht2002}
```

In the main document the citation works and Latex uses my citation, but if I delete the quote in the main document Latex does not work properly, because he does not link the used reference and therefore can not quote properly. If I used the citation in the main document, like above, it works also in the included chapter. I really despair here so does anybody know some tricks to get Latex use my included citation?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Please reformulate your example in compilable form, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}.  That will give potential helpers something to work with directly, and not to have to make any assumptions.

Comment: Which tex system are you using? Does it work if you use \input instead of \include?

Comment: Ms. Fischer, thank you so much for your help it was so easy and now I am very happy to asked my qeustion here. It actually worked by using the \Input instead of \include. I do not excactelly know why but it workes! Best regards Kai